# jQuery ajax post using FormData() append data element can't find the appended data element after post

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I use the code from talkerscode.com to implement file upload using drag and drop. The code is working. Now I would like to add additional input value during in the same ajax post. I add an input tag called "user_id" in the following html code. And I append the element into the formdata object. After the change drag and drop upload still work, but the PHP code complain the $_POST["user_id"] is not defined. Here is my code. Please help!

```
<html>
<!-- code original from talkerscode.com -->
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="upload_style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<input type="text" name="user_id", id="user_id" value="1228">
<input type="file">
<div id="drop-area">
 <h3 class="drop-text">Drag and Drop Images Here</h3>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
 $("#drop-area").on('dragenter', function (e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).css('background', '#BBD5B8');
 });

 $("#drop-area").on('dragover', function (e){
  e.preventDefault();
 });

 $("#drop-area").on('drop', function (e){
  $(this).css('background', '#D8F9D3');
  e.preventDefault();
  var image = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;
  createFormData(image);
 });
});

function createFormData(image)
{
 var formImage = new FormData();
 formImage.append('userImage', image[0]);
 formData.append('user_id', $('#user_id').val());
 uploadFormData(formImage);
}

function uploadFormData(formData)
{
 $.ajax({
 url: "upload_image.php",
 type: "POST",
 data: formData,
 contentType:false,
 cache: false,
 processData: false,
 success: function(data){
 $('#drop-area').html(data);
 }});
 }
 </script>

 ----------------PHP code -------------------

<?php
    if(is_array($_FILES))
    {
     if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name'])) {
     $sourcePath = $_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name'];
     $targetPath = "images/".$_FILES['userImage']['name'];
     if(move_uploaded_file($sourcePath,$targetPath)) {
?>
   <img src="<?php echo $targetPath; ?>">
   <p> user_id = <?php echo $_POST["user_id"] ?> </p>
   <?php
   exit();
  }
 }
}
?>


-----------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 function createFormData(image) {
  var formImage = new FormData();
  formImage.append('userImage', image[0]);
  formData.append('user_id', $('#user_id').val()); //change formData to formImage
  uploadFormData(formImage);
 }
```

From:

```
  formData.append('user_id', $('#user_id').val());
```

to:

```
  formImage.append('user_id', $('#user_id').val());
```

Comment: After I apply your change PHP no longer complain about undefined for $_POST["user_id"]. but no value was returned. It suppose to return 1228.

Comment: can you try to `console.log($('#user_id').val())`

Comment: I check there is value after the formImage.append('user_id', $('#user_id),val()); by using alert(" user_id " + $('#user_id),val());

Comment: I check the post I see something like this. Content-Disposition: form-data; name="user_id"                                                                                                    1228

Comment: Can i see the data using `print_r($_POST, true);`

Comment: Hi aldrin27 it work now in jQuery/javascript and HTML. But it didn't work under bootstrap environment. I don't know why.